# How to fetch single row in one to many mapping using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class A {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private int    id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
   private List<B> details;
   ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "test1")
public class B {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private int    id;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;
   ......
}
```

**Criteria**

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .add(Restrictions.in(id, list))
List = criteria.list();
```

As there are many matching rows with id "1" I would get below result. But I need only first one

**Result :**

```
{
  "id":1,
  "details":[
     {
        "name":abc,
     },
     {
        "name":123,
     },
     {
        "name":xyz,
     },
 }
```

**Trying to get result as below : Only first row instead of all the rows from test1 table (B.class)**

```
 {
  "id":1,
  "details":[
     {
        "name":abc,
     }
 }
```

I am using hibernate criteria to fetch results. I want to limit the data retrieved from joined table (one to many mapping). Is this possible?

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: DO you want to implement  pagination ??

Comment: No. Please see my update

Comment: Can you please give code that you have use in your service ??

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are aiming at, but:

**1** if you know there will be only result then use:

```
Entity criteria.uniqueResult();
```

**2** if you expect many you can do an order and then set the number of top results that you want (first ten below):

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(/* field*/));
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(10);
criteria.list();
```

Comment: As there is one to many relation, I would get list of values from second table that is  - private List<B> details; I want to get only first row instead of entire list.

Comment: please add plain sql of your idea. Lets make this more clerar

Comment: I have updated the description to make it more clear with JSON I am expecting